# How can I change space between a given background image in a pattern. The image is mandatory online

Tags: css, design-patterns, background-image

I'm making this background using just online images and want to control the space between those in the pattern. Is there any way to achieve this using just CSS? I know you could use `round` and `space` but in general would be more useful to control specifically the amount of space between them.

Here's the code:

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #fff89c;
  background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/869/869078.svg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 50px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-pattern">
</div>
```

In this research, I've found nonetheless, really cool posts about backgrounds and this it's super useful: https://24ways.org/2011/css3-patterns-explained

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an SVG by simply increasing the `background-size` you can create the space because the SVG will try to keep its ratio:

```css
div.background-pattern {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #fff89c;
  background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/869/869078.svg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 50px 100px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-pattern">
  </div>
```

Or

```css
div.background-pattern {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #fff89c;
  background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/869/869078.svg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 100px 50px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-pattern">
  </div>
```

You can also combine with gradient to hide some of the pattern thus have more control on the space:

```css
div.background-pattern {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #fff89c;
  background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 0,transparent 50px,#fff89c 50px,#fff89c 100px),
    url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/869/869078.svg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%,100px 50px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-pattern">
  </div>
```

Here is another example where you can use the background twice to have another kind of pattern:

```css
div.background-pattern {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #fff89c;
  background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 0,transparent 50px,#fff89c 50px,#fff89c 100px),
    url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/869/869078.svg"),
    url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/869/869078.svg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%,150px 50px, 150px 50px;
  background-position:left top,left top, 60px 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-pattern">
  </div>
```

By combining all the above techniques you have full control of the space between the pattern.

Comment: Man! Really cool way! I've searched a lot and this answer is simple, nice and useful! Really thanks Temani! 